# How to migrate to "Component Routes" in React Router 6.9.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So far I'm using *React Elements* for *React Router*:

```
...
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>...</div>}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            </Routes>
        </Suspense>
    );
```

How do I use the new *Component Routes* like `const componentRoutes = [{path: '/', Component: Home }]` ?

Comment: New component routes? Can you clarify what the question is?

Comment: Any clarification on what exactly you are asking for help with?

Answer (score 0):

You can find in document: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial

And here is my suggest:

```
import {createBrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

import HomePage from "../pages/home-page/HomePage";
import ProfilePage from "../pages/profile-page/ProfilePage";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <HomePage />,
    },
    {
        path: "/profile",
        element: <ProfilePage />,
    }
])

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <RouterProvider router={router} fallbackElement={<>Loading...</>}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I hope it's helpfull with you.

Comment: Your snippet still uses `element: <AnyComponent />`, but not `Component: AnyComponent`.